# how can I schedule a reboot in Linux?

Tags: linux

I'm new in Linux and I want to schedule a reboot at midnight. How should I do it?

**Edits:**

- I'm sorry I didn't put the complete details. I want a reboot every 3rd Saturday of the month at 23:30.
- I don't know what's wrong but I cannot find crontab. What I have is `cron.d`; `cron.daily`; `cron.weekly`; `cron.monthly`;

I'm sorry for the noob question. Pls help me. Thanks.

Comment: The real question is why you'd want to be doing this regularly, do you have a leaky application or something? If you're scheduling regular reboots to solve a problem then you've probably got a bigger problem...

Comment: Do you want it to reboot every night?

Comment: I'm not voting down, because it's sort of a policy decision (and I think nightly reboots are a bit excessive), but regularly scheduling reboots across an infrastructure are a decent way of ensuring that machines have up to date kernels and all services running are patched. I've heard a 3 month uptime limit as being a good middle ground.

Comment: If this was a comment on the question, rather than an answer, I would upvote it.  Actually I would change my mind, because the question was ambiguous about whether this was a one-time or regular thing.  :)

Comment: @Matt Simmons: so you don't keep track of the patches you apply and reboot when its required?

Comment: @symcbean - Sure, but if you reboot everything at the same time, then...well, you lose service availability AND it's chaos. I can see advancing the schedule because of a critical vulnerability, but every small kernel upgrade doesn't mean "install-it-now-or-dire-circumstances-ensue".

Comment: @Matt Simmons: If you can't reboot a server without losing service, then you've got architecture problems you really should fix.

Comment: symcbean: Yes, however if you do updates and reboots across the board, all at once, you lose service because the other members of the service group go down too. I think we're arguing about the same thing ;-)

Comment: I'm sorry I didn.y put the complete details. I want a reboot every 3rd Saturday of the month at 23:30

Comment: `/etc/crontab` entry like `30 23 15-21 * 6 /sbin/shutdown -r now` will reboot at 23:30 on the 3rd Saturday of every month.

Comment: i dont know what's wrong but i cannot find the crontab..? what i have is the cron.d;cron.daily; cron.weekly; cron.monthly; I'm sorry for the noob question.Pls help me. thanks

Comment: You don't need to edit a file for crontab, just use the command "crontab -e" as root and it will open a text editor for you.  By "as root", we mean either type "su -" first and then enter the root password that was set up when the server was set up, or just type "sudo crontab -e" and enter your password.  Which to use depends on your version of Linux.

Comment: First, check to see what time it is on the system you want to reboot, using the `date` command. Is its clock in sync with your local time? If not, you may want to take that into consideration.

Answer (score 69):

Type `shutdown -r 0:00` and it will reboot at midnight.

If you want to reboot each night, add a cron entry using crontab -e as root to run shutdown -r each midnight

```
@midnight shutdown -r now
```

Comment: A time argument is mandatory, you can use `now`.

Comment: No ... if he want a one time command and want to type the command now, he should add the time !

Comment: @No, it needs a time argument such as `now` in the crontab line.

Comment: Oups yes sorry, I misread Tobu comment and think he tells 0:00 was useless in the first command... I edited to correct (and Massimo answers too)

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing what other `@{command}` variables are available.

Comment: Note that issuing `shutdown -r 22:00` then closing the terminal will cancel the reboot command.    `nohup shutdown -r 22:00 &` for maintaining the reboot command after closing the terminal window.

Comment: The computer rebooted immediately!!

Answer (score 18):

Another option is the [at](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_%28Unix%29) command, available on many Linux distributions.  See the man page for more info, but the general syntax for your purpose would be:

> echo "reboot" | at 0000 jun 27

To quote the OS X man page:

**at** - *executes commands at a specified time*

Sound like what we're talking about. ;)

Answer (score 17):

Using `crontab`.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crontab

Adding this entry to /etc/crontab should do:

```
0 0 * * * /sbin/shutdown -r now
```

Comment: `shutdown` needs a time argument such as `now`

Comment: This will do the reboot every night. I am not sure if this is what he wants.

Comment: The original question made it sound like he wanted it rebooted every night. He actually wants it rebooted every 3rd Saturday, which would still be easiest with a crontab

Comment: i dont know what's wrong but i cannot find the crontab..? what i have is the cron.d;cron.daily; cron.weekly; cron.monthly; I'm sorry for the noob question.Pls help me. thanks

Comment: It depends on the distribution you're using, but usually you should find a file called "crontab" in your system's /etc directory. You should also be able to examine the current crontab using the command "crontab -l", and to edit it using "crontab -e".

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you cannot use cron to schedule tasks for "last Friday of each month" or "third Thursday in each month". 
What you can do, however ugly it seems, is to have a script run every Saturday at 23:30 and then have this script determine if this particular Saturday is the third Saturday of the week (can be done using date and maybe cal commands).

I hope this helps. I have not found an elagant solution to this problem. I found this thread, because I was searching for a solution for the same problem.

Comment: the comments above of "30 23 15-21 * 6 /sbin/shutdown -r now" will work. It'll basically only run on the third week of the month, but only when it's also saturday

Comment: I do not think this cron line works as you think it does.

Comment: I created the following two lines:
"30  23    1-7   *   4 date" and "30  23    1-7   *   3 date".
I got *two* mails last night both saying: "Wed Mar  7 23:30:02 CET 2012"

Comment: the last field matches the day of the week, with zero being sunday. the 4 cronjob should not have matched on a wednesday.

Comment: That is what I meant. The rule you wrote do not mean what you think it means. It will trigger the job every day for a week. No matter the weekday.

Comment: hmmm, appears you're right. that's pretty crappy isn't it !

Comment: Yeah. Very. So what to do about this? I can hardly imagine that Linux and Unix admins do not have this scheduling need.

Answer (score 1):

1) at the command line type *`which reboot`*
2) once you know where reboot is located (usually /sbin/reboot) cd into one of the the directories in /etc/cron.daily , /etc/cron.weekly , /etc/cron.hourly etc... ie *`cd /etc/cron.weekly`*

3) create a file (using nano or vim) call it zzreboot and add the following lines:

#!/bin/sh
/sbin/reboot

The reason you want to call the file zzwhatever is to make sure it's the last job called after all other jobs. To make sure just do an *`ls -l`* in the directory and verify it's the last file.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, still I would like to answer it.
On your terminal logged in as root follow below steps:

1. #`crontab -e` this would open the cron file to write your cron jobs
2. add a new line like`30 23 15-21 * sat /path/to/reboot`. This cron job would reboot the system every 3rd sat of the month at 11.30 pm.
3. save and exit