# 3rd party software for linux restarting scheduler

Tags: linux, task-scheduler

Are there 3rd party softwares for linux restarting scheduler?

Comment: Can you be clearer as to what you're looking for?  What do you want to schedule?

Comment: In a previous question, the OP wanted to know [how to schedule a reboot](http://serverfault.com/questions/155239/how-can-i-schedule-a-reboot-in-linux). Perhaps this is related.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there 3rd party softwares for linux restarting scheduler?

WTF? The scheduler is a core part of the kernel and cannot be managed independently from user-space. Do you mean crond/atd? Something else?

Why does it need to be restarted?

Assuming you have a valid reason for restarting crond, then use crond to schedule an atd job - or if its atd you want to bounce, restart it directly from crond. But I suspect the question you are asking has nothing to do with the problem you are trying to fix.

C.

edit:

And why do you think you need 3rd party software to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Scheduled restarts of servers aren't usually a good idea, unless you're closely monitoring it to be sure it comes back up.

Your best option would be to install a monitoring tool like Nagios, but this would require a significant invest of time to setup. If you edit in more details of what you're trying to accomplish perhaps we can come up with a better solution.

Comment: Restarting a service, monitoring a service (watchdog/heartbeat), or restarting the server? I thought the question was ambiguous there.

Comment: @Bart, good point; I hadn't thought of that. Though I'm still thinking most services probably shouldn't be restarted without some monitoring for the service to come back up.